# Ingress argocd-server returning 404 on eks

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I have the following configuration

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "argocd_ns" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "argocd"
    }

    name = "argocd"
  }
}


resource "helm_release" "argocd" {

  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.argocd_ns]

  name       = "argocd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  version    = "3.31.0"

  namespace = "argocd"

  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/argocd_values.yaml", {
      host                = var.argocd_dns_name
      git_repo            = var.argocd_repo_url
      ssh_key_secret_name = "gitlab-deploy-key"
    })
  ]
}
```

This is my argocd_values.yaml

```
appVersion: 1.7.6
version: 2.11.3
server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    hosts:
    - ${host}
    https: true
    tls:
    - secretName: argocd-tls
      hosts:
      - ${host}
  extraArgs:
  - "--insecure"
  config:
    kustomize.buildOptions: "--enable_apha_plugins"
    repositories: |
      - url: ${git_repo}
        sshPrivateKeySecret:
          name: ${ssh_key_secret_name}
          key: ssh_key
  additionalApplications:
  - name: apps
    project: <redacted>
    source:
      repoURL: ${git_repo}
      targetRevision: HEAD
      path: apps
    destination:
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
      namespace: argocd
    syncPolicy:
      automated:
        prune: true
        selfHeal: true
  additionalProjects:
  - name: foo
    description: "<REDACTED>"
    destinations:
    - namespace: foo
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    sourceRepos:
    - '*'
    destinations:
    - namespace: foo
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    clusterResourceWhitelist:
    - group: '*'
      kind: '*'
    namespaceResourceBlacklist:
    - group: '*'
      kind: '*'
```

This is what I see when I do

```
kubectl describe ingress -n argocd


Name:             argocd-server
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=server
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=argocd
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of=argocd
                  helm.sh/chart=argo-cd-3.31.0
Namespace:        argocd
Address:          <REDACTED>.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  argocd-tls terminates <REDACTED>
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  <REDACTED>
                     /   argocd-server:443 (172.31.100.155:8080)
Annotations:         cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
                     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                     kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: argocd
                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: argocd
                     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                  From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----                 ----                       -------
  Normal  CreateCertificate  25m                  cert-manager-ingress-shim  Successfully created Certificate "argocd-tls"
  Normal  Sync               7m51s (x3 over 25m)  nginx-ingress-controller   Scheduled for sync
```

If I try to access to the url I'm getting a 404 nginx error, the thing is if I forward the port to my localhost I'm able to open the argo cd dashboard, what could be wrong here? Let me know if you need anything else from my terraform code